# meaning of "pared bone" in ""Her singing voice [...] a bright soprano, clean and pure as pared bone"

Tags: meaning-in-context, literature

I'm reading *The Versions of Us* by Laura Barnett and the following sentence is describing one of the characters' voice:

> "Her singing voice - she was training at the conservatoire in Vienna when she fell pregnant with Eva - is a good octave higher: a bright soprano, clean and pure as **pared bone**."

I looked up the dictionary and it says "to pare" can mean "to remove", "to reduce", or "to peel". But I still don't understand what a "pared bone" is. Is it a sharpened, polished bone? Or a very thin piece of bone? And therefore I can hardly imagine what kind of voice is like a "pared bone". Can anybody explain the idea for me?

Comment: Bone from which the meat has been cut cleanly and completely away. Perhaps we're meant to think of a bone flute?

Comment: @TRomano: My father can [play spoons/bones](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WclGUCAdLh8), but I don't think the bones would "clack" very well if they still had shreds of meat on them. As for using dirty spoons...

Answer (score 1):

In short, pared bone is a bone which has had every vestige of flesh, sinew, grease and gristle removed. You may recognize this more readily called by its more common name: Ivory. Here's a picture below (though this bone has been pared into a carving as well):

[image: Decorated Ivory retrieve from Wikimedia]

With that in mind, is *"...a bright soprano, clean and pure as ivory."* a bit easier to picture?

Comment: Yes. Thanks a lot. Ivory renders a more beautiful feeling than bone.